# execute tasks on multipe hosts in one playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that automatically adds hosts to our monitoring system. The first part runs on the monitoring server while the second part runs on a client. Currently I'm running it with `hosts: all` and executing it with `ansible-playbook -l new_client`.

```
- hosts: monitoring_server
   tasks:
   - name: generate pki
...
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
   - name: downloading icinga2 repository
```

When executing the playbook, the first task returns `skipping: no hosts matched`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [host patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html), such as:

```
- hosts: all:!monitoring_server
```

to execute play an all hosts except those in `monitoring_server` group (or host if it is an individual host).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to execute the playbook using `all:!monitoring_server` in the second host field and executing it with `ansible-playbook -l "new_client, monitoring_server"`